# Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial: Chapter 6 Section 6.3.2 Password and Confirmation (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I am followed Michael Hartl's http://ruby.railstutorial.org until Chapter 6.3.2 where I stuck at Password and Confirmation.
( http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec:adding_a_secure_password )

I have added "attr_assessor :password, :password_confirmation' to User.rb from what I understand after reading the instruction stated below:

"As seen in the mockup in Figure 6.1, we expect to have users confirm their passwords, a common practice on the web meant to minimize typos. We could enforce this at the controller layer, but it’s conventional to put it in the model and use Active Record to enforce the constraint. The method is to add password and password_confirmation attributes to the User model, and then require that the two attributes match before the record is saved to the database. Unlike the other attributes we’ve seen so far, the password attributes will be virtual—they will only exist temporarily in memory, and will not be persisted to the database."

I get 11 failures on bundle exec guard on user_spec.rb after adding:

```
password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar" to @User.new in models/user_spec.rb
```

Something like "virtual" attributes (password, password_confirmation) that do not exist in db:development.sqlite3. This is what I am trying to do with no success.  I even tried all possible methods such as hashes with @User in user.rb

What did I do wrong here?

Thanks kindly in advance

```
file: spec/user_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    # @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                    password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password)}
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end      
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.com A_USER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end      
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

.

```
file: models/user.rb
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :integer         not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  email           :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime        not null
#  updated_at      :datetime        not null
#  password_digest :string(255)
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  # attr_accessible :email, :name
  # attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  #validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  #validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

end
```

Comment: It looks to me like it should be working, could you post up the error reasons for the failures. I will try to recreate it on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only on section 6.3.2 then the tests should be failing.  You will be correcting that in the following sections.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I ve spent 2 days on it! I have missed the line states "has_secure_password" in user.rb which described in section 6.3.4 and listing 6.30. Many Thanks

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot...I just spent so much time trying to figure out why it wouldn't pass

Answer (score 2):

Adding has_secure_password to the model fixes the problem.  It's in the book (later part) too.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the errors are complaining about "Could not find table 'users'"
Try:

```
rake db:migrate 
rake db:load:test
```